# When an electron is excited to a singlet state, must it flip its spin state to enter the triplet state and flip once more to the ground state?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, fluorescence, phosphorescence

I understand the Jablonski diagram in that it has intersystem crossing from the singlet state to the triplet state, but how many spin switches are necessary to complete to phosphores? When an electron is excited to a singlet state, must it flip its spin state to enter the triplet state and flip once more to the ground state?

Comment: Yes. At least it ends up being reversed again. "Where that happens" escape my competence.

Comment: Yes two spin flips, one to form triplet and then again to reform the singlet ground state. See the answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112814/how-fast-is-the-interconversion-triplet-%e2%86%92-singlet-in-organic-molecules